# Eigenvalues of Markov matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

I was trying to prove that a Markov matrix always has an eigenvalue 1 but I seem to have proved that all eigenvalues of a Markov matrix are equal to one! Could anyone look at my work and point out the mistake?

Let $P$ be a Markov matrix with all rows summing to 1, i.e. $\sum_j P_{ij} = 1 $ for all $i$.
Let $\lambda$ be a right eigenvector of P with eigenvalue $\alpha$. Then

$$
\sum_i \lambda_i P_{ij} = \alpha \lambda_j
$$

Let's sum both sides over j:

$$
\sum_{i,j} \lambda_i P_{ij} = \sum_j \alpha \lambda_j
$$
which gives

$$
\sum_i \lambda_i = \sum_j \alpha \lambda_j
$$
which gives $\alpha = 1$! But there should be eigenvalues that are not equal to 1 as well.

Comment: Shouldn't $\alpha\lambda_k=\sum_j P_{kj}\lambda_j$ for fixed $k$?

Comment: I think that would be the case if we were looking at left eigenvectors, but I want to look at right eigenvectors here.

Comment: You only get $\ \alpha=1\ $ if $\ \displaystyle\sum_j\lambda_j\ne0\ $.  What you have shown is that the entries of left eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues other than $\ 1\ $ must sum to $\ 0\ $.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I just realised this after playing with an example!

Comment: But can I just check - I believe that it should be entries of right eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues other than 1 that must sum to 0. Bearing in mind that P was defined so that its rows sum to 1 - do you agree with this?